# Calling WebService using AJAX XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services

JavaScript Part:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:21085/WebService1.asmx?op=GetModelsByID";
request.open('GET', url );
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
        document.writeln(request.responseText);
    }}
request.send();
```

WebService Part:

```
    namespace JavaScriptAjax
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {[WebMethod]
     public string GetModelsByID()
    {
     return ("jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj");}}}
```

but request.responseText doesn't return anything.
Is it possible to call a Webservice like this or I have to use SOAP?

Comment: Have you confirmed the web service returns text, by calling the service url from a browser? Use `console.log(request)` to inspect the request object. Use a tool like fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the http request and response is what you expect.

Comment: I use VisualStudio2012 , when I trace step by step, after send the request object is not null but it's contain the whole webservice url Html page.

Comment: I've checked the state, the readyState is 1 . how can I solve it? is the problem with the url? or what?

Comment: Use SOAP UI and test the service then once that is working try creating a client for it. I see a couple of problems allready this is not a REST service it is a SOAP service and you are using a HTTP GET and though some SOAP clients might support GET most SOAP services preffer POST due to size limitations.